# Expain the result of "explain" query in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

I am using indexing for mysql tables.

My query was like this

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `logs` WHERE userId =288 AND dateTime BETWEEN '2010-08-01' AND '2010-08-27'
```

I have indexing on field userId for this table logs,
and the result of explain query is like below.

```
id  select_type     table     type  possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1      SIMPLE         logs     ref      userId      userId      4       const   49560   Using where
```

The question is "My indexing is really useful or not?"...

Thanks in advance

@fastmultiplication

I thought that indexing on both this field might increase load on mysql as there will be lot of entries with unique (userId and dateTime). 
I have tried adding indexing on both userId_dateTime and the result is

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys            key        key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1      SIMPLE        logs    ref     userId_dateTime    userId_dateTime     4       const   63455   Using where
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is using indexes, and yes, they are useful. You might find the following doc pages useful:

[EXPLAIN Output Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html)
[How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html)
[Multiple-Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Also:

[Multiple column index vs multiple indexes](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/08/22/multiple-column-index-vs-multiple-indexes/)

MySQL will usually use the index that returns the smallest number of rows.  In your first example, MySQL is using the `userId` index to narrow down the number of rows to 49560.  That means that `userId` does not contain unique values (if it did, you wouldn't need the date range condition).  As there is no index on the `dateTime` column, it then has to scan each row to find the ones that meet your date range criteria.

In your second example, you appear to have created a compound (multiple-column) index on `userId` and `dateTime`.  In this case, it appears as though MySQL is not able to use the latter half of the index for the `BETWEEN` clause—I'm not sure why. It may be worth trying it with two separate indexes, rather than a multiple-column index.  You may also want to try replacing `BETWEEN` with:

```
'2010-08-01' >= AND <= '2010-08-27'
```

This should be identical, but see the following bug report, which may affect your version of MySQL:

[Optimizer does not use index for BETWEEN in a JOIN condition](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28612)

Answer (score 1):

From the 'rows' field it looks like MySQL still estimates it will have to look at a lot of rows.

You should try adding an index to the dateTime field, too.

And for this particular query, maybe an index on both of the fields.

```
alter table logs add index user_datetime (userId,dateTime);
```

Comment: I have entered more detail in question , please check

Answer (score 0):

How many rows *should* the query return? And how fast is the query running?

It looks to me like a pretty simple query, which is using the correct index, so if it is slow for some reason, it is probably because it has to actually return a lot of data. If you are not actually interested in all the rows, you can use `LIMIT` to get less.